# Gradle complaining on wrong Android support libraries versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I want to use a GraphView in my app, and so I added `implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'` to my app-level `gradle.build` file.

However that causes an error stating that all `com.android.support` libraries should have the same version.

It gives `com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1` as an example (all of the libraries I explicitly use are `26.1.0`).

I suppose it's a dependency of the GraphView library, but I don't know what to do next.

My target SDK version is 26 so I can't change all the other versions to 27. What can I do to use this library?

Comment: Why you can't port to 27 ? You need to use the same  dependency version for all your APIs. I recommend you use the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step:

1>If compileSdkVersion is 27 You have to change to 27
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmihJ.png)

2>If you still caught error uninstall and install SDK Target version from SDK Manager.